# JFaceTooltip does not appear on a subsequent hover after ESC is pressed

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a class that extends ColumnViewerToolTipSupport. This class overrides createViewerToolTipContentArea() and provides custom content for the tooltip.
When there is a mouse hover on the treeitem the tooltip appears and can be focused too. When the tooltip is in focus, ESC key press will cause the tooltip to disappear. I think this property is inherited from jface tooltip.

Problem here is once the tooltip is closed by ESC action, it will not appear again after hovering, unless another treeitem is hovered and its tooltip is appeared.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Are you saying your code does something to focus the tooltip?

Comment: setHideOnMouseDown(false); this is called inorder to keep the tooltip active upon mouse click

Comment: My code does not do anything on focus. Focus is provided only so that scroll bars can be used

Answer (score 0):

`ColumnViewerToolTipSupport` specifies the `ToolTip.NO_RECREATE` flag to prevent a new tool tip being created while the hover stays in the same area. It defines the area as the current `ViewerCell` (a cell in a row).

So, yes, this is expected behavior.

Comment: Even when I use ToolTip.RECREATE flag, the same problem exists

Comment: You still haven't answered the question about what you are doing about focus. We can't help when you don't provide adequate information.

Comment: May I know if hitting ESC when a tooltip is opened causes the tooltip to dispose or just hide it??

Comment: ESC is just the normal key that a Shell accepts to close the window so it is disposed.